# I actually WANT a blocking write to a linux named pipe

Tags: java, linux, named-pipes

I have a threaded application. In one thread I want to write data streamed from a database to a named pipe and I want the writes to block if the reader (the command line program "zip" in this case) can not keep up with the java thread. Data that goes into a single Zip file entry might be bigger than main memory of the system.

I see the following behaviour regardless if using FileOutputStream or FileWriter when writing to the named pipe:
The writes would buffer until the java heap is filled up and then actually slow down the thread to the reader's speed. For a single threaded process this is only a waste of space but for a multithreaded process this lets run other threads into out of memory exceptions.

The only remaining option I see is to use JNA to do a blocking write in C. Other suggestions are welcome.

BTW. the very reason that I let the "zip" tool do the compression is that java.util.zip and Lingala's Zip4J would fill the RAM with buffers.

OK here is a small condensed example. I create a named pipe "fifo" using "mkfifo fifo" and start "zip --fifo -fz -v fifo.zip fifo" to have the reading process block on the named pipe.
Then I start the follwoing java program with say -Xmx32M.
Without the "Mem Eater" thread it behaves as described above. With it this thread will run in an OutOfMemoryException.
Now for the code:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class fos {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        if (argv.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage is:");
            System.err.println("java fos.java <fifo>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        String fifoName = argv[0];
        
        startMemConsumerThread();

        try (var fifoWriter = new FileWriter(fifoName)) {
            for(long i=0L; i< Long.MAX_VALUE; i++)
                fifoWriter.write("Hello World! "+i+"\r\n");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void startMemConsumerThread() {
        final int NUM_CHUNKS = 20;
        final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024*1024;
        final List< byte[] > chunks = new LinkedList<>();
        
        var t = new Thread("Mem Eater") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    while (chunks.size() < NUM_CHUNKS)
                        chunks.add(new byte[CHUNK_SIZE]);
                    chunks.remove(NUM_CHUNKS % 7);
                }
            }
        };
        
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the code which actually does the writing.

Comment: "The writes would buffer until the java heap is filled up" This is not normal, you must have made a mistake. Show your code

Comment: The point is that neither FileWriter nor FileOutputStream will block on writing to a named pipe with a slow reader.

Comment: So you have one thread blocked writing to the pipe, while another thread is running in parallel, using more and more memory. Are you expecting *all* threads to be paused when one thread has to wait for i/o? That's fundamentally not how threads work

Comment: Is the problem that you have a *producer* thread that keeps queueing data in memory, and a *consumer* thread that reads from the queue, but the consumer is slower than the producer? You have to create a mechanism to apply *back pressure* so that the producer is forced to slow down too

Comment: @Joni: at least you grasped the structure of my problem. In the above example fifWriter.write does not block when a libc call to write would block but instead it fills the JVM's memory with buffers (I can see them on the heap). All I want is some Java IO-routine to write to a named pipe that would have the same blocking behavior as the system call write.

Comment: Where are these buffers, which class owns them? FileOutputStream should have very little overhead, it holds no buffer of its own. FileWriter adds a small fixed size buffer to make character encoding conversion more efficient. I don't see how they would end up filling your heap. And writing to both definitely blocks the caller if the underlying native library call blocks.

Comment: @Joni: you are completely right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a thin JNA wrapper around open, write, close to have the blocking behavior of write. Now I no longer observe unbounded memory consumption but the Java heap will grow to the configured maximum and GC will handle it gracefully.

I have to correct myself: even when using FileWriter.write the blocking takes place and the memory consumption is bound. Thanks to joni for pushing me!

But things go out of control when using java.util.ZipOutputStream for this use case. But that is another story...